# Element-wise Comparison of Two Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare two columns in pandas. I know I can do:

```
# either using Pandas' equals()
df1[col].equals(df2[col])
# or this
df1[col] == df2[col]
```

However, what I am looking for is to compare these columns elment-wise and when they are not matching print out both values. I have tried:

```
if df1[col] != df2[col]:
    print(df1[col])
    print(df2[col])
```

where I get the error for 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous'
I believe this is because the column is treated as a series of boolean values for the comparison which causes the ambiguity. I also tried various forms of for loops which did not resolve the issue.
Can anyone point me to how I should go about doing what I described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get hold of the index where the column values are not matching. Once you have that index then you can query the individual DFs to get the values.

Please try the fallowing and is if this helps:

```
for ind in (df1.loc[df1['col1'] != df2['col1']].index):
    x =  df1.loc[df1.index == ind, 'col1'].values[0]
    y =  df2.loc[df2.index == ind, 'col1'].values[0]
    print(x, y )
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 9, 4, 7]})

if not df2[df2['col1'] != df1['col1']].empty:
    print(df1[df1['col1'] != df2['col1']])
    print(df2[df2['col1'] != df1['col1']])

Output:
    col1
2     3
4     5
    col1
2     9
4     7
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Try this. You could use any of the following one-line solutions.

```py
# Option-1
df.loc[df.apply(lambda row: row[col1] != row[col2], axis=1), [col1, col2]]
# Option-2
df.loc[df[col1]!=df[col2], [col1, col2]]
```

**Logic**:

**`Option-1`**: We use `pandas.DataFrame.apply()` to evaluate the target columns row by row and pass the returned indices to `df.loc[indices, [col1, col2]]` and that returns the required set of rows where `col1 != col2`.

**`Option-2`**: We get the indices with `df[col1] != df[col2]` and the rest of the logic is the same as `Option-1`.

### Dummy Data

I made the dummy data such that for indices: 2,6,8 we will find column 'a' and 'c' to be different. Thus, we want only those rows returned by the solution.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.arange(10)
c = a.copy()
c[[2,6,8]] = [0,20,40]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': a**2, 'c': c})
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
   a   b   c
0  0   0   0
1  1   1   1
2  2   4   0
3  3   9   3
4  4  16   4
5  5  25   5
6  6  36  20
7  7  49   7
8  8  64  40
9  9  81   9
```

### Applying the solution to the dummy data

We see that the solution proposed returns the result as expected.

```py
col1, col2 = 'a', 'c'
result = df.loc[df.apply(lambda row: row[col1] != row[col2], axis=1), [col1, col2]]
print(result)
```

**Output**:

```
   a   c
2  2   0
6  6  20
8  8  40
```